# What is the function of std::cout ? Is it similar to simple cout?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I can't make out what std::<**something**> means.

Actually I wanted to ask what was this **std::** part doing here and what it denoted?

Comment: If you have `using namespace std;` before `cout`, they're identical. Go read about [namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace).

Comment: When you say `std::<something>`, you are telling your compiler to use the `<something>` function from the `std` namespace.

Comment: there is nothing like "simple `cout`".  [example](http://rextester.com/NMY73294)

Comment: Not in this case, but there *might* be differences like [`std::clog`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/clog)  being an output stream, while "plain" [`clog`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/clog) computes a complex number logarithm.

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning -- sort of; `std::<something>` refers to the **name** `<something>` in the namespace `std`. The name can refer to things that aren't functions. In particular, `std::cout` (and `cout`, as well) is not a function.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for the correction! It's definitely important to be specific with these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, you are just starting with `C++`.
So lets start with the `std::` part. This is called a namespace. Namespaces are sometimes confusing people, but they are very useful.
A namespace is just little container that can hold `class`es, `enum`s, `sturct`s and all the other things in one place.

Why are they useful?
Well, for example, if you are writing a painting program and that program is interacting with graphics, both may contain classes named `color` and `point`. If you have no namespace, it would be **impossible** to do so!

Then comes the `cout` part. `cout` is an actual class in the `std` namespace, kind of like the `Color` class in above example. So as an example, here is a simplified example of `paint` and `grahpics`:

```
namespace paint {
    class Point {
        private:
           Color color;
           int x, y;
        public:
           Point(Color c, int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy), color(c) {
           }
           // Continued code...
    };

    class Color {
        private :
            int red, green, blue;
        public:
            Color(int r, int g, int b) : red (r), green (g), blue (b) {
            }
            // Continued code...
    };
}
```

and GUI:

```
namespace gui {
    class Window {
        private :
            Point position;
            int width, height;
            Color background_color;

        public:
            Window(Point p, int w, int h, Color b) : position (p), width (w), height (h), background_color (b) {
             }
    };

    class Color {
        private:
            Color_type c;
            Point point;

        public
            enum Color_type {
                red=0xff0000, green=0xff00, blue=0xff, white=~0x0, black=0x0
            };  

            Color(Color_type cc, Point p) :c(cc), point(p) { } 
            // Continued code...
    };

    class Point {
        private:
            int x, y;

        public:
            Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {
            }
            // Continued code...
    };
}
```

So, as you can see,  you  can have namespaces to encapsulate different classes with the same name.
How do you use them is **easy**:
You just add the namespace's name in front of it (e.g `paint::color` or `gui::color`). Here is an example:

```
int main (void) {
    paint::Point paint_p(Color(2,2,2), 55, 33);
 p(55, 33);

    // or

    paint::Color paint_c(0, 0, 0); // Produces black;
    gui::Color gui_c(gui::Color_type::black);
}
```

To sum it up **`<something>`** is class name or variable name, or perhaps a nested namespace (a namespace inside a namespace), but in case of `cout`, it is the name of a class.

I hope this explains it.

Comment: Wow you really broke it down very well. @Gox Thanks. So the user can also create its own namespaces?

Comment: @Programmer exactly